# How can I make the game stops for a while everytime someone scores, instead of rhush back to the game?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, game-physics

I'm building a game to practice my skills. Everytime someone scores a point, the game starts again really fast and I'd like it to give it a little time before going back. The main function looks like this:

```
function drawGame() {

    background(); //does the background
    
    drawChar();

    drawEnemy();

    drawBall();

    changeMovement();

    playerControls();

    enemyFollowsBall();

    enemyChangePosition();

    checkBallCollision();

    drawScore();

    //if(pointScored()) {
       //setInterval(drawGame, 1000);
//}

    setTimeout(drawGame, 1);
}
```

The function keeps being called through setTimeOut, which manages the game animations. I tried to solve my problem with the commented out code (I set pointScore(), which increments the score and does some resetting, to return true), but it didn't work as I expected. How can I obtain the expected effect?

Comment: `drawGame` is effectively called again immediately because of the 1 millisecond timeout. Have you tried increasing the timeout time?

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Yes, thanks, but that makes the game slower as well, and that is unwanted

Comment: Then we need to take a look at `drawScore`. I assume that's the function that's supposed to wait a bit after the player scores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would still call `setTimeout(drawGame, 1);` when you dont move it into the else statement or add a return after.

```
function drawGame() {

  background(); //does the background

  drawChar();

  drawEnemy();

  drawBall();

  changeMovement();

  playerControls();

  enemyFollowsBall();

  enemyChangePosition();

  checkBallCollision();

  drawScore();

  if (pointScored()) {
    setInterval(drawGame, 5000);
    return; // either this
  } else { // or adding the else here
    setTimeout(drawGame, 1);
  }

}
```